# Signature in my generated csr is invalid. What can be the probable reason?

Tags: c++, cryptography, pki, csr, pkcs#10

I am using safenet sdk's library to generate public key and private key in Dongle. Then, I am sending public key as bits to my swift application. I am also signing my certification info with private key using safenet sdk's library then sending the signature to swift application. Then, I have generated csr with both public key bits and signature. According to csr decoder, the signature is invalid. What could be the reason behind this?

My public key is

```
MIIBIzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCARAAMIIBCwKCAQEA6oMT0+efRAV83xZcwKQGkTKz7vh1oziher267nuV/Bfj67oR3aWQV5wY+chVuTm+8tLV0RDIUzlwBnBnKKBAoj6orszgpZu87rg8VJWjegMQZjOC5LQgX10ZAG00M613Mktlk89mlNBwxgMcG5CrFSl1kxYWm49ZIeavKRi5jwEjQLfaJrTFTZCm4qyVhs8imiN9p7sbzUHJv4hQoDCp2NIm9ApES9dZSjl3TYCpHO3qlfcNfRo74NMf1q0bJ83yrLjJY45uAI9ifK0I7A+PfSFCdhX2datzWY5QRYwq+d43XSJ+JJXK8um1kI88pQFfcspNVcg8a/+pY9T9SSyP0QIEAOqDEw==
```

My Signature is (in hex)

```
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
```

My generated csr is
Now the csr is

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

But it says that "signature is invalid in my csr"

Key pair generation code is

```
void Dongle::generateKeyPair(char* enrollmentId, char* password) {
    CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
    CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    
    printf("\nThis sample demonstrates how to search for an object based on provided attribute template and how to generate an RSA key pair using PKCS#11 functions.\n\n");
    
    LoadCryptoki(pkcs11_path);
    
    CHECK_RV(GetFirstSlotId(&slotId));
    
    CHECK_RV(fl->C_OpenSession(slotId, (CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | CKF_RW_SESSION), NULL_PTR, NULL_PTR, &hSession));
    
    Dongle::generateKeyPairUtil(hSession, password, enrollmentId);
    
end:
    if (hSession) ;
    UnloadCryptoki();
    
}
    
    // Find the matching object. There should be only a single match since there is only one on the token.
    C_FindObjects(hSession, &hObject, 10, &found);
    
end:
    fl->C_FindObjectsFinal(hSession);
    return (found < 1) ? CK_INVALID_HANDLE : hObject;
}

CK_OBJECT_HANDLE Dongle::generateKeyPairUtil(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession, char *password, char *enrollmentId) {
    CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
    CK_BBOOL    bFalse  = CK_FALSE;
    CK_BBOOL    bTrue   = CK_TRUE;
    CK_KEY_TYPE keyType = CKK_RSA;
    
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPublicKey  = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPrivateKey = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    
    std::string labelPub = std::string("public") + enrollmentId;
    std::string labelPriv = std::string("private") + enrollmentId;
    
    
    CK_UTF8CHAR * labelPublic  = convertToCK_UTF8CHAR(labelPub);  //Label of public key.
    CK_UTF8CHAR * labelPrivate = convertToCK_UTF8CHAR(labelPriv); //Label of private key.
    
    // Setup public key attributes.
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS  classPublicKey = CKO_PUBLIC_KEY;
    CK_ULONG         vecModulusBits[] = { 2048 };
    CK_BYTE          publicExponent[] = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 };
    
    CK_ATTRIBUTE publicKeyTemplate[] =
    {
        { CKA_CLASS,            &classPublicKey,    sizeof(classPublicKey)      },
        { CKA_LABEL,            labelPublic,        strlen((char*)labelPublic)  },
        { CKA_KEY_TYPE,         &keyType,           sizeof(keyType)             },
        { CKA_TOKEN,            &bTrue,             sizeof(bTrue)               },
        { CKA_PRIVATE,          &bFalse,            sizeof(bFalse)              },
        { CKA_MODULUS_BITS,     &vecModulusBits[0], sizeof(vecModulusBits[0])   },
        { CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT,  &publicExponent,    sizeof(publicExponent)      },
    };
    
    // Setup private key attributes.
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS  classPrivateKey = CKO_PRIVATE_KEY;
    CK_ATTRIBUTE privateKeyTemplate[] =
    {
        { CKA_CLASS,            &classPrivateKey,   sizeof(classPrivateKey)     },
        { CKA_LABEL,            labelPrivate,       strlen((char*)labelPrivate) },
        { CKA_KEY_TYPE,         &keyType,           sizeof(keyType)             },
        { CKA_TOKEN,            &bTrue,             sizeof(bTrue)               },
        { CKA_PRIVATE,          &bTrue,             sizeof(bTrue)               },
    };
    
    // Setup mechanism to generate an RSA key pair.
    CK_MECHANISM mechanism;
    memset (&mechanism, 0, sizeof (mechanism));
    mechanism.mechanism = CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN;
    
    // Login to the token with a user password.
    C_Login(hSession, CKU_USER, (CK_UTF8CHAR_PTR)password, strlen(password));
    
    // Try to find the two RSA keys with a specific label using the FindObject() function.
    hPrivateKey = FindObjects(hSession, privateKeyTemplate, DIM(privateKeyTemplate));
    hPublicKey  = FindObjects(hSession, publicKeyTemplate,  DIM(publicKeyTemplate));
    
    // Generate a new RSA key pair if an RSA key with the same label doesn't exist on the token.
    if ( ! (hPublicKey && hPrivateKey) )
    {
        printf("Wait for RSA key pair generation ... \n");
        rv = C_GenerateKeyPair(hSession, &mechanism, publicKeyTemplate, 7, privateKeyTemplate, 5, &hPublicKey, &hPrivateKey);
        
        if (rv == CKR_OK) {
            printf("OPERATION SUCCESS. Key Pair Generated Successfully.\n");
        }
    }
    
    else {
        printf("Key Pair Already Exists \n");
    }
    
end:
    C_Logout(hSession);
    return hPrivateKey;
}
```

Comment: I also cannot verify the self-signed signature. Your public key has a very unusual public key exponent of 15368979. This is legal, it's just very rare and a hint that something has gone wrong somewhere. Almost everything out there generates public keys with an exponent of 65537. You'll need to show the code that generates this. Is there any chance you used a modern signature algorithm like RSA-PSS?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question with the code.

Comment: Actually, the CSR creation code would be just as important. But anyway, I have found a couple of problems. The signature in the CSR can be 'decrypted' if the public exponent is set to 65537. The result appears to be formatted as expected for a PKCS1 ver 1.5 type 1 signature block, but the hash inside doesn't have the correct value. At this point all I can say is that something has gone very wrong, it almost looks like you have a Franken-csr, a mix of different CSRs.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable informations. i resolved the modulus issue. But still the signature is invalid. I am using swift to develop the application. But, the safenet sdk's library is written in C. So, I had to convert Data to NSData or NSString.In both case, the signature is invalid. I have added changed csr in question.

Comment: I have identified the issue. I am converting Data to SecKey, then again SecKey to Data for same public key. I thought both public key string will be the same. But, surprisingly, they are not the same. Is there any way around in swift for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know swift.